# STM32F4 interfacing with NRF24l01+

Tags: wireless, stm32, nrf24l01

Like the title says I want to use a NRF24l01+ with a STM32F4. So far, I realized the communication with two NRF24l01+ and two Arduino but I would like to exchange on Arduino with the STM32. I looked up the internet an found this site: http://www.wvshare.com/product/Open407Z-Package-B.htm but no library for it. Has someone tried it or has a library?

Comment: That ST part has several asynchronous serial interfaces and several SPI ports, so whichever you are using you should be able to interface at least two modules with it.  However beware that various peripherals share pins, so using some other functions may block the pins you'd need for these engines, especially on the low pin count packages.

Comment: thanks, I know that. I am more iterested in a documented   library.

Comment: Check out [nAN24-12](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/nordic/download_resource/10638/11/84899525) and use it as basis for the library you will write yourself.

Comment: thanks, that looks quite complex for a newbie like I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found a libary for the STM32F4. Here is the link:  [STM32F4 NRF24L01 - libary](http://www.wvshare.com/product/NRF24L01-RF-Board-B.htm)